# Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/ir.vitrinsaz1.main/files/Vitrin/Images/image1449295087849.png

Tags: android

I would like to take photo. but when I want to use this function, I got error message :

```
  public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

---

error message :

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/ir.vitrinsaz1.main/files/Vitrin/Images/image1449295087849.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

my manifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: The file doesn't exist.  You said you want to take a photo, but this code is to open an existing file.  Something here is a bit confused.

Comment: first you have to check file are exits or not. What you pass in String path variable ?